# Created Date is incorrect in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, date-time, whencreated

I am not sure why this is happening and is there a way to rectify it. The date in the created column of my list is showing as 2018. This list or the site did not exist back in 2018 then how come the date is showing as 2018.

PS: The uploads happened from a MAC user.

Any help is appreciated

[image: incorrect Date and Time in created column]

Answer (score 0):

I need to collect the following information:

1. What is the correct time of the created time?
2. How do the user create items in the list? Just create items one by
   one? or create items from code?
3. Have you customize your list?
4. Does the issue exists in one special list or all lists? Try to
   create a new list, let MAC user to create items and compare the
   results.
5. Does the issue exists for one user or all users?

There are 2 types of time zone settings in SharePoint: Regional and Personal will impact the dispaly of the time.

Setting proper SharePoint Time Zone for users for your reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/

Comment: 1. the correct time is between March and April 2020
2. The SharePoint is synced to onedrive so once the user uploads to onedrive the list gets updated
3. I have just added a few columns created being a read-only column remains untouched
4. This is very peculiar, the same user has a few other documents uploaded the same way and it all has the correct created time.